Intermittent No suitable HttpMessageConverter error during API calls in Spring Boot – how to troubleshoot?
Issue Details:
The error appears randomly during API calls, and the log shows:
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [X] and content type [application/json]

After restarting the application, the issue typically does not resurface until the next release or redeployment. The same issue does not occur in the local environment when I try to simulate load (I used tools to simulate high concurrency with 10,000 requests).
RestTemplate Configuration:
I have a custom RestTemplate bean defined in a configuration class, where I explicitly add MessageConverters, including MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to handle JSON responses.
The issue occurs despite ensuring that the RestTemplate is configured properly with converters at startup.
Behavior Observed:
When I initialize RestTemplate in the configuration class, it shows 7 MessageConverters. However, during runtime (when making an API call), I notice the RestTemplate has 16 MessageConverters, suggesting that converters are being added somewhere during the application lifecycle. The RestTemplate is injected into the service using @Autowired, and no @Qualifier or additional RestTemplate beans are being used.
What I've Tried:

I excluded RestTemplateAutoConfiguration to avoid auto-configuration of RestTemplate, but the issue persists.
I’ve checked for multiple RestTemplate beans and made sure the correct instance is being used.
I added logging around RestTemplate initialization to track when the MessageConverters are being modified, but I can’t pinpoint the source of the change.
High concurrency tests locally don’t reproduce the issue, which mostly happens in production or staging environments.

Error Log Example:
The error message I see in the logs is:
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [X] and content type [application/json]

The HttpMessageConverter for application/json should be present (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter), but it appears to get lost or altered at some point during runtime.
Key Questions:

What could be causing additional MessageConverters to be added to the RestTemplate after it has been initialized?
Could concurrency or load affect the behavior of HttpMessageConverter, and how can I better reproduce this locally?
Is there a way to reinitialize the RestTemplate bean or the converters dynamically in case this issue arises, as the problem seems to go away after restarting the app?

The below is my restemplate configuration :
@Bean
@Primary
public RestTemplate restTemplate()
{
setTrustStore(); // setup certs
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory());
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(CustomInterceptors().Builderof().build());
return restTemplate;
}

Any guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue or suggestions for a potential root cause would be greatly appreciated!

If this is Spring Boot why are you defining your own RestTEmplate with converters? Why aren't you using the RestTemplateBuilder to create one based on the default configuration? Add your configuration to the question.

Added as suggested.
